# Привязка Points of interest к своей метке

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Нужно чтобы по щелчку на свою метку открывался балун существующего на карте POI(points of interest).

Answer (score 0):

Такой функциональности к сожалению нет.